# Loop to check duplicate random numbers in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, random

how to create a query in MYSQL, to compare a random number with the previous random numbers and if it exists it should generate another random number

Comment: Where all previous number stored? Are they in another table?

Comment: How are you generating the random numbers and where are you storing it?

Comment: Did u used any table for storing the previous random numbers. Plz provide more info.

Comment: i am able to generate random id using left(uuid(),36) . i need some code to check this generated id with existing id's in same table name is users .. colum name id which is having primary key.

Comment: set @id1=LEFT(UUID(),36);
set @count1=select count(*) from users where id=@id1;
if(@count1<=0)
then
insert into users(id,user_name,first_name,last_name,title,address_street,email1,phone_work,
department,status,created_by,modified_user_id,user_hash,date_entered,date_modified,
employee_status)
values(@id1,"kis","kis","ch","mr","iuiuik2i","kish@gmail.com","IT",
"Acti","AD","AD","QW,curdate(),curdate(),"Active")

Comment: i have used above code for inserting data

Comment: set @count1=select count(*) from users where id=@id1; if(@count1<=0), i am using this query for checking duplicate random id but it is not working, it is giving compilation error everytime

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to create unique random numbers without duplication:

```
SELECT CAST(RAND() * 99999 AS INT) as mycol
FROM yourtable
WHERE "mycol" NOT IN (SELECT PreviousRand FROM yourtable)
LIMIT 1
```

I am assuming the your are storing the values in the table.

Comment: LOL. `"mycol"` is a string and will never be found in `SELECT PreviousRand FROM yourtable`